# Generic exception submitting form via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, onerror

I am moving an application from JBoss 7.1.q to WildFly.   Parts of the navigation are done with by creating a form in JavaScript and submitting it via the submit method.   All of these calls still work with the exception of one.

Instead of navigating to the page, I get a message of

> A Generic Exception Occurred while accessing this page.

I grepped through the code to see if someone had created a window.onerror function to catch exceptions but could not find one.  Even more odd, I added one to the js page and it failed to catch the exception.

I have waded through the JavaScript with Firebug and Chrome dev tools and from what I can see, everything looks to be OK, but clearly it is not.

I know it is not much to go on.  I am looking for ideas for the next steps to triage this issue.  I also find it curious that this problem did not appear until the move to WildFly but I have no clue how that could cause this issue - maybe the form posting is more strict?

Any ideas?

Comment: Just read a link that says to make sure your account has write privileges on all the directories involved. Easy enough that it's worth a try I think.

Comment: sounds more like a server error? Can you get a more detailed stack trace of the error from your app? (look in console/log files)

Comment: Caught the call in Charles proxy, call does appear to be hitting the server.  Nothing in the logs or console but it is a place to start.